# TypeError: Cannot read property 'mytest' of undefined

Tags: typescript, swagger

I'm using swagger api, when I call the end point it says error `Cannot read property 'mytest' of undefined`

```
class User {
  private mytest(req:any, res:any, next:any){
    return res.json('test32423423');

  }
  public loginByJSON(req: any, res: any, next: any) {
    this.mytest(req,res,next);
  }
}

const user = new User();
export = {
  loginByJSON: user.loginByJSON
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the way JavaScript works with function context (`this`) if you reassign the function it will take the context of the object it is assigned to. That is to say `this` will actually refer to the object you are creating.

There are several ways to handle this mainly revolving around keeping the context with the object instance.

```
{
  loginByJSON: user.loginByJSON.bind(user),
}
```

You can also use instance-bound methods:

```
loginByJSON = (req: any, res: any, next: any) => {
  this.mytest(req, res, next);
}
```

Then the method will *always* be bound to that instance. The disadvantage of this is that a new function is created for every instance, but `.bind` will do that anyway and in this case it seems like you're just doing this for organizational purposes and only ever creating once instance.

Comment: Why don't you export the class and create the instance where it's needed?

Comment: Those logic handling by swagger-node-runner which is swagger dependency package. it looks for controller file and its method based on swagger.yaml